# xpath function not recognized in xslt

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

I am debugging an xslt stylesheet in Oxygen using the xalan processor. I cannot seem to get the current-time() or hours-from-time() functions to work. I get a "could not find function" error. What am i doing wrong? here is the code.

`<xsl:variable name="isPm" select="hours-from-time(n1:TIME_REPORT) &gt;= 12"/>`

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and a solution for the `current-time()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[hours-from-time](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-hours-from-time) and [current-time](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-current-time) are XPath 2.0 functions. Xalan only supports XPath 1.0.

Later versions of Xalan support extension functions which will give some of this functionality. Both of the function you are looking for are there, in some form. Note that since XPath 1.0 doesn't understand date times you'll be dealing with strings.  But see, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="date">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Current Date Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <h1>It's now <xsl:value-of select="date:date-time()"/>.</h1>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See both the [Xalan Extension Function](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html) page and also the [EXSLT Extension Function page for Dates and Times](http://www.exslt.org/date/index.html).

Comment: Is there any way to get the current time in xpath 1.0?

Comment: Nice one! This worked like a charm. I had already passed in the current hour in as a parameter as in Dimitre's solution below. Since this solution will also help me in the future if i need to use other unsupported XPath function i have marked it as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> I am debugging an xslt stylesheet in Oxygen using the xalan processor.
> ```
>
> I cannot seem to get the
>   current-time() or hours-from-time()
>   functions to work. I get a "could not
>   find function" error.

As noted by @lavinio and @Alejandro, these two functions were introduced in XPath 2.0, which is not supported by Xalan.

**You may pass the current time as a parameter to the XSLT 1.0 transformation**.

**Do note**, that even in XPath 2.0, multiple evaluations of the [**`current-time()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-current-time) during a transformation, return the same value. So this function doesn't give you anything more than what you get by passing the current time as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Those aren't standard XPath 1.0 functions. If your processor has those functions implemented as extensions, then you should add the correct namespace for them.

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Extension-Functions

> If a FunctionName in a FunctionCall
>   expression is not an NCName (i.e. if
>   it contains a colon), then it is
>   treated as a call to an extension
>   function. The FunctionName is expanded
>   to a name using the namespace
>   declarations from the evaluation
>   context.
>
> If the XSLT processor does not have an
>   implementation of an extension
>   function of a particular name
>   available, then the `function-available`
>   function must return false for that
>   name. If such an extension function
>   occurs in an expression and the
>   extension function is actually called,
>   the XSLT processor must signal an
>   error. An XSLT processor must not
>   signal an error merely because an
>   expression contains an extension
>   function for which no implementation
>   is available.
>
> If the XSLT processor has an
>   implementation of an extension
>   function of a particular name
>   available, then the `function-available`
>   function must return true for that
>   name. If such an extension is called,
>   then the XSLT processor must call the
>   implementation passing it the function
>   call arguments; the result returned by
>   the implementation is returned as the
>   result of the function call.